# Is there an equivalent in .NET DI to Simple Injector's RegisterConditional?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm trying to go as native .NET as possible with a project I'm working on but the reference project I'm migrating has some Simple Injector registrations. Here's a line I'm stuck on

```cs
container.Register<IValidator<Foo>, FooValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Bar>, BarValidator>();

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IValidator<>),
    typeof(ValidateNothingDecorator<>),
    LifeStyle.Singleton,
    c => !c.Handled);
```

This is from the [Simple Injector documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced) and I'm wondering if there's an equivalent way to do this on the built in .NET 6 `IServiceCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no equivalent for `RegisterConditional` in MS.DI, and I'd say that in many cases you're out of luck, in this particular case you are likely using the `ValidateNothingDecorator<T>` as a fallback in case no explicit (non-generic) registration exists. This can be done as follows in MS.DI:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Foo>, FooValidator>();
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Bar>, BarValidator>();

// Register open-generic fallback
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(ValidateNothingDecorator<>));
```

In MS.DI a registration for an open-generic type always functions as fallback; in other words, if there exists an explicit registration for a specific closed version (e.g. `IValidator<Foo>`) of the given open-generic interface (e.g. `IValidator<>`), the closed version is selected.

This is not how it works with Simple Injector. In Simple Injector you explicitly have to specify the conditional registration is the fallback using the `!c.Handled` lambda. This design is chosen explicitly to make the registration process less implicit and less error prone. Using this design, it allows Simple Injector to validate the correctness of the registrations, because Simple Injector does not implicitly chose from multiple applicable registrations; it forces to you specify what you meant.

Comment: Thanks so much Steven. As it happens this migration I'm doing to .net 6 is a framework based on your "Meanwhile... on the <xxx> side of my architecture". It's something I've running for awhile. Originally I'd used AutoFac but with newer .net I decided to re-factor alot of stuff. I've kinda ditched the idea of IServiceCollection only and using SI. Whilst everything is now ready to go, I can't seem to get my SI registered services cross wiring. Will tinker and see if I can work it out. Thanks again for the reply